# Draw a graph with node size and edge width proportional to number of repetitions

Tags: python, graph, networkx

I'm working on a paper that is similar to [this](https://www.pnas.org/doi/10.1073/pnas.0305937101). I have to draw a directed graph that looks similar to [the one](https://www.pnas.org/doi/10.1073/pnas.0305937101#fig2) presented in the paper.

I work primarily in Python, and have explored various options in matplotlib, seaborn and networkx to draw a similar graph, but could not work it out. The input of nodes in my case are a few list of binary numbers of fixed length for a graph. Here I am giving example of binary number of length 5, but the length can go upto 15. So you can imagine the number of all possible nodes can become really large!

For example, the lists that represent the paths may look like:

```py
all_possible = [f"{i:>05b}" for i in range(2**5)] # Code to generate all possible states
# Paths taken by the graph
path1 = ['start', '01101', '00001', '11000', '11100', '00010', '00100', 'end']
path2 = ['start', '10001', '00111', '01100', '01110', '10000', '11000', '00101', '11011', '01010', 'end']
path3 = ['start', '11100', '01001', '01100', '00011', '10111', '10000', '00001', 'end']
path4 = ['start', '01100', '01110', '11111', '11011', '10001', '11011', '11101', '00000', 'end']
path5 = ['start', '10001', '11100', '01101', '01001', '01000', '00101', '11001', '00101', '11100', 'end']
```

You can imagine the paths all starting from `start` state and ending at `end` state. In between they go via various combinations of the possible states. For `path1` it goes like `start -> 01101 -> 00001 -> 11000 -> 11100 -> 00010 -> 00100 -> end`

Now as more and more edges will merge to, for example node `11100`, it should become larger or at least change color to indicate a larger number. Same goes for edges, i.e. if same edge is traversed multiple times, for example the edge `01100 -> 01110` should be wider to represent the number of times it was traversed.

So far I have tried various solutions, but the closest one would be with `networkx` module:

```py
def draw_complete_graph(all_graph_edges: list, fig_size: tuple = (50, 50), graph_img_name: str = "test_graph"):
    G = nx.MultiDiGraph()
    plt.figure(figsize=fig_size)
    for single_edge in all_graph_edges:
        G.add_edge(
            single_edge[0],
            single_edge[-1],
            weight=all_graph_edges.count(single_edge),
            width=all_graph_edges.count(single_edge),
        )
    width_list = list(nx.get_edge_attributes(G, "width").values())
    nx.draw(
        G,
        with_labels=True,
        node_shape="o",
        width=width_list,
        connectionstyle="arc3, rad = 0.1",
        nodelist=["start", "end"],
    )
    plt.savefig(graph_img_name)
    plt.close()

def get_all_edges(all_paths: list[list]) -> list:
    graph_edges = list()
    for single_path in all_paths:
        graph_edges.append((single_path[0], single_path[1]))
        for ix, node in enumerate(graph_edges[1:-2]):
            graph_edges.append((node, single_path[ix + 1]))
    return graph_edges

if __name__ == "__main__":
    edges = get_all_edges([path1, path2, path3, path4, path5])
    draw_complete_graph(edges)
```

But this does not give me such a result.

My first thought was, is it even possible to do anything close to the graph linked above with Python3? If possible, please help me out and point out what else should I add to reach closer to the graph I require.

Comment: The article has contact information for the authors, you should just ask them how to produce the plot, or at least what packages were used.

Comment: Thanks, That is a great idea. I will try to contact them and update if I find anything! Also thanks for the edits, I was not sure if seaborn supports this that's why I tagged with it. I hope to find some answer related to networkx.

Comment: Also this is a very old paper, so I'm not sure if what they used are relevant or available now. But I just wanted to know if this type of graph is reproducible with current Python modules. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example using [netgraph](https://github.com/paulbrodersen/netgraph). The same can be achieved with just networkx but then you have to work out the order in which the nodes and edges are stored in the `nx.Graph` instance as networkx draw commands only accept lists, not dictionaries, for properties such as node size, edge width, node color, and edge color.

Here, I am using a `log(x+1)` transformation to map node and edge traversals to node size/color and edge width/color. You may need to find a different transformation for your real data. The guiding principle is to map highly skewed distributions such as the traversal counts to flat distributions, in which the unique values that are present in your data are easily separable and don't cluster too much.

[image]

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
"""
Reproduce https://www.pnas.org/doi/10.1073/pnas.0305937101#fig2
"""
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import networkx as nx

from matplotlib.colors import LogNorm
from matplotlib.cm import ScalarMappable

from netgraph import Graph, get_radial_tree_layout # pip install netgraph / conda install -c conda-forge netgraph

if __name__ == '__main__':

    g = nx.balanced_tree(3, 3, create_using=nx.DiGraph)
    node_positions = get_radial_tree_layout(list(g.edges))

    # invert edges as the networkx constructor creates the tree inside-out
    h = nx.DiGraph([(v2, v1) for (v1, v2) in g.edges])

    # compute node and edge traversals
    node_traversals = {node : 0 for node in h}
    edge_traversals = {edge : 0 for edge in h.edges}
    for node in h:
        if node != 0: # center
            paths = nx.all_simple_paths(h, node, 0)
            for path in paths:
                for node in path:
                    node_traversals[node] += 1
                path_edges = list(zip(path[:-1], path[1:]))
                for edge in path_edges:
                    edge_traversals[edge] += 1

    fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1, 2)

    # option 1: using node size and edge width
    node_size  = {node : np.log(count+1) for node, count in node_traversals.items()}
    edge_width = {edge : np.log(count+1) for edge, count in edge_traversals.items()}

    Graph(h, node_layout=node_positions, arrows=True,
          node_size=node_size, edge_width=edge_width, ax=ax1)

    # option 2: using colors
    node_colormap = ScalarMappable(norm=LogNorm(vmin=1, vmax=np.max(list(node_traversals.values()))), cmap='copper')
    edge_colormap = ScalarMappable(norm=LogNorm(vmin=1, vmax=np.max(list(edge_traversals.values()))), cmap='copper')

    node_color = {node : node_colormap.to_rgba(count) for node, count in node_traversals.items()}
    edge_color = {edge : edge_colormap.to_rgba(count) for edge, count in edge_traversals.items()}
    Graph(h, node_layout=node_positions, arrows=True,
          node_color=node_color, edge_color=edge_color, ax=ax2)

    plt.show()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will explore `netgraph` module once and read through the options I can apply on the graph to satisfy my additional constraints that are not mentioned in this question. But this solution looks promising for the problem.